# Best way to deploy with Flask android and website

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 flask applications one for site and one for android.The first application rendering templates and the second return json on every request.I am about to deploy and i am wondering what's the best option.I 've made a little research and i have some options:

1. deploy 2 apps in different servers
2. deploy 2 apps in same server
       in different virtual enviroments
3. convert 2 apps in one and deploy
       them using blueprints.

I think that the first option is the worst.So i don't know if it's better idea to have 2 apps running in the same server with a domain and a subdomain like myapp.com and android.myapp.com or convert the into one and deploy it as it is.
I am using blueprints and i try to find something like blueprints of blueprints so i can use a main blueprint "site" with it's children blueprints and a second blueprint "android" with it's children blueprints but i didn't find something.
I need a little help because it's the first time i am deploying and i am a little confusing.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go around this:

1. Move all your APIs to some other route, say `/mobile/<route>` and modify your android application to follow the `/mobile` API.
2. Get the user-agent from the request headers and then return your response accordingly :

   ```
   from flask import request
   request.headers.get('User-Agent')
   ```

Alternatively, use the [`request.user_agents`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/utils/#module-werkzeug.useragents) string to get more information about the device which is requesting the data.

Personally, I would recommend using the `/mobile` route for deploying it. But it is really up to you.